# How to generate database from classes using EF Code First [.Net 5.0]

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-5

I'm working on `C#` `winForms` project **(.NET 5.0)** , Iam a newbie in `EntityFramework` `code first`, I worked with `EF DB First` many times but I decide to go through `EF Code First`.

**My Class**

```
class Student
{
    public int    ID   { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**My Db Context class I created**

```
class XMDBContext:DbContext
{
    public XMDBContext() : base()
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to know how can I use `Visual Studio` or `Entity Framework` to generate the `database`(preferred if in SQL Server) from these `classes` ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to create the database in a code first scenario. But the easiest approach would be to just run your application and read or write to the DbContext. It will then automatically create the database "on access".

The official microsoft example is also very helpful if you are doing this the first time: [Code First to a New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database)